# How to open up open source .NET Core libraries with Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity

Now that .NET Core libraries are open source, how do I can open up a single git cloned library with Visual Studio 2019?

For example, if you clone the [AspNetCore project](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore) from git; at first you'll face a bunch of libraries like Identity, SignalR, etc in one place

[image]

And inside of each library folder, you'll face some .slnf files, etc

[image]

and if you just try to open the .slnf with VS it will load the entire project, besides you'll get suggestion about downloading some extra components for VS

[image]

So

1. What extra components are exactly required to just study the codes?
2. How to open a single library (like Identity) with .slnf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity is one component of the whole AspNetCore. Components depend on each other forming a "hierarchy tree".

As your screenshot shows, AspNetCore has 491 projects.

An `.slnf` is a `solution filter`: a view of only a subset of the complete solution, but that is aware of the whole solution. The `Identity.slnf` includes 83 of the 491 projects, basically the Identity components plus all the dependencies that needs to be built first (i.e. other referenced projects). Use `IndentityNoDeps.slnf` for a more filtered view (with no deps) that is more focused on the Identity part.